# Returning values even the result are empty

Tags: php, sql, empty-list

I have a table that is similar below.

```
     |  user_id  |   point_1  | point_2  | point_3
        453123        1234         32       433
        321543         1           213      321
```

My query is something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_id = 12345 OR user_id = 987654321"
```

Obviously, this will return nothing since `user_id` 12345  OR `user_id` 987654321 do not exist on the table.

But I still want to return something like the one below :

```
|  user_id   |   point_1  | point_2  | point_3
    12345           0           0         0
  987654321         0           0         0
```

Comment: what rdbms are u using ?

Comment: SELECT [user_id], Max(Point_1), Max(Point_2), Max(Point3)
FROM (SELECT 12345 ,0,0,0
UNION
SELECT 987654321, 0, 0, 0
UNION
SELECT [user_id],   [point_1], [point_2] , [point_3] from Your_Table WHERE user_id = 12345 OR user_id = 987654321) DontKnowWhy
GROUP BY [user_id]

Answer (score 1):

You could use an inline view as a rowsource for your query. To return a zero in place of a NULL (which would be returned by the outer join when no matching row is found in my_table, you can use the `IFNULL` function.

e.g.

```
SELECT s.user_id
     , IFNULL(t.point_1,0) AS point_1
     , IFNULL(t.point_2,0) AS point_2
     , IFNULL(t.point_3,0) AS point_3
  FROM ( SELECT 12345 AS user_id
         UNION ALL SELECT 987654321
       ) s
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table t
    ON t.user_id = s.user_id
```

NOTE: If datatype of `user_id` column my_table is character, then I'd enclose the literals in the inline view in single quotes. e.g. **`SELECT '12345' AS user_id`**.  If the characterset of the column doesn't match your client characterset, e.g. database column is latin1, and client characterset is UTF8, you'd want to force the character strings to be a compatible (coercible) characterset...  **`SELECT _latin1'12345' AS user_id`**

Answer (score -1):

Your desired result resembles the result of an `OUTER JOIN` - when some records exist only in one table and not the other, an `OUTER JOIN` will show all of the rows from one of the joined tables, filling in missing fields from the other table with `NULL` values.

To solve your particular problem purely in SQL, you could create a second table that contains a single field with all of the `user_id` values that you want to be able to show in your result. Something like:

```
+-----------+
| user_id   |
+-----------+
| 1         |
+-----------+
| 2         |
+-----------+
| 3         |
+-----------+
| ...       |
+-----------+
| 12344     |
+-----------+
| 12345     |
+-----------+
| 12346     |
+-----------+
| ...       |
+-----------+
```

And so on. If this second table is named `all_ids`, you could then get your desired result by modifying your query as follows (exact syntax may vary by database implementation):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    all_ids AS i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    my_table AS t ON i.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE
    i.user_id = 12345 
        OR i.user_id = 987654321;
```

This should produce the following result set:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| user_id   | point_1  | point_2  | point_3  |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 12345     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 987654321 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

It should be noted that this table full of IDs could take up a significant amount of disk space. An [integer column in MySQL can hold 4,294,967,296 4-byte values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html), or 16 GB of data sitting around purely for your convenience in displaying some other data you *don't* have. So unless you need some smaller range or set of IDs available, or have disk space coming out your ears, this approach simply may not be practical.

Personally, I would not ask the database to do this in the first place. Essentially it's a display issue; you already get all the *information* you need from the fact that certain rows were *not* returned by your query. I would solve the display issue outside of the database, which in your case means filling in those zeroes with PHP.

Comment: This is a bit over the top, don't you think?  Having a table with ~2 billion values (for an `INTEGER` type, 8+ GB)?  Especially because most times you're only interested in rows that already exist?  There's much better ways to get this information.  Yes, a number table can be handy, but you don't usually but this many values in them.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I think the OP has given us an MCVE and their true use case may be more complex. I made no claims about this being the best solution or a practical approach in all cases but it does work. It's also far more flexible than an indeterminate number of `UNION`s and `IFNULL`s and may be significantly more performant. Perhaps the next person to find this Q&A only needs 100,000 ID values, and for them, this is the best solution. But I suppose some discussion of the space requirement is called for.

Answer (score -1):

You can't get the result you want using only a select statement.  Only rows that exist somewhere will be returned.

The only way I can think to do this is to insert the query values into a temp table and then outer join against that for your query.

So the basic process would be:

```
create table temp1 (user_id integer);

insert into temp1 values (987654321); -- repeat as needed for query.

select t.user_id, m.* from temp1 t left outer join my_table m on m.user_id = t.user_id;

drop table temp1;
```

This isn't very efficient though.

Comment: Actually, the result can be returned using only a SELECT statement. You are right to point out that a row source is needed for the SELECT; a temporary table is one approach, but it's also possible to use an inline view (within the SELECT itself) as a rowsource. e.g. `SELECT t.user_id, ... FROM ( SELECT 123 AS user_id UNION ALL SELECT 456 UNION ALL SELECT 789 ) t LEFT JOIN my_table m ON ...`

Comment: @spencer7593: You are correct, of course!  What I wrote isn't quite what I meant (that a 'simple' select, as presented by the asker, on its own won't work). I probably should have left that line out.